# Cakephp: How to link models if each model connected to other by some foreign key

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model, relation

I am new to Cakephp and I don't found any solution for my problem.
I have three tables-
**medicines:**

```
id|Name|company_id
```

**companies:**

```
id|Name|city_id
```

**cities:**

```
id|Name
```

I have to select medicines.name, companies.name and cities.name where ids are matched so
how I cand do this by Cakephp method.
I know the simple sql query for this:

```
SELECT medicines.name, companies.name and cities.name FROM medicines, companies, cities WHERE medicines.company_id=companies.id AND companies.city_id=cities.id
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the book? It is well explained there: [Associations: Linking Models Together](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html)

> Defining relations between different objects in your application
>   should be a natural process. For example: in a recipe database, a
>   recipe may have many reviews, reviews have a single author, and
>   authors may have many recipes. Defining the way these relations work
>   allows you to access your data in an intuitive and powerful way.

Examples from the book:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasOne = 'Profile';
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Recipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
            'conditions' => array('Recipe.approved' => '1'),
            'order' => 'Recipe.created DESC'
        )
    );
}


class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MyRecipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
        )
    );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'MemberOf' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
        )
    );
}

class Group extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MyRecipe' => array(
            'className' => 'Recipe',
        )
    );
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Member' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I read the book and I didn't find a proper solution though I can relate tables medicines and companies relation in Medicine Model and companies and cities relation with belongsTo in Company Model but I want to relate all three table in single query(Model)

Comment: @AshishTripathi did you try what you found in the book? Cake automatically joins the tables for you if you set the proper relationships. Just set the 'recursive' property as needed.

Comment: @AshishTripathi why bind and unbind? Just set the relationships in your Model files as showed in the book. Generally you don't need to unbind them